# как сравнить текущую строку и ту, которая появляется на ее месте при ajax запросе

Tags: php, jquery

как сравнить текущую строку и ту, которая появляется на ее месте при ajax запросе. В частности я хочу реализовать такой механизм, который будет обновлять курсы криптовалют и сопровождать это цветами. Так вот вопрос, как мне сравнить эти значения

```
$("document").ready(function() {
        function get() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'pars.php',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data) {
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    $('.btc').text(obj.resmath1);
                    $('.xrp').text(obj.resmath2);
                    $('.eth').text(obj.resmath3);
                    $('.eos').text(obj.resmath4);
                    $('.ltc').text(obj.resmath5);
                    $('.xuc').text(obj.resmath6);
                    $('.bth').text(obj.resmath7);
                    $('.dash').text(obj.resmath8);
                    var a = $('.ltc').text();
        плоды моих фантазий// if( a > obj.resmath5 ){$('.ltc').addClass('green');
                   //                       }else{
                   //     $('.ltc').addClass('red');
                   // }
                }

            });

        }

        get();
        setInterval(get, 1000);

    });
```

сам ajax запрос
так же интересно, как реализовать добавление класса на определенное время.Спсибо

HTML

```
<tr> 
<td><img style="width:30px;" src="images/Litecoin.png"/></td> 
<td>LTC</td> 
<td>Litecoin</td> 
<td class="ltc td"><center><img style="width:20px;" src="images/giphy.gif"></center></td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: "и сопровождать это цветами" - рекомендую гладиолусы

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  function updateValue(elClass, elValue) {
    var $el = $('.' + elClass + ' span');
    var oldValue = +$el.text();
    var newValue = +elValue;
    $el.text(elValue);

    $el.removeClass("green red");
    var class1 = (oldValue > newValue) ? "green" : "red";
    $el.addClass(class1);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $el.removeClass(class1);
    }, 1000);
  }
  var i = 1;
  function get() {
    setTimeout(function(data){ // to simulate asynchronicity
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      updateValue('ltc', obj.resmath5);
      setTimeout(get, 1000);
    }, 1, JSON.stringify({ resmath5: i++ }));
    
    /*$.ajax({
      url: 'pars.php',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        updateValue('ltc', obj.resmath5);
        // ...
      }
    });*/
  }

  get();
});
```

```css
.green {
  color: green;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
<tr>
  <td><img style="width:30px;" src="images/Litecoin.png" /></td>
  <td>LTC</td>
  <td>Litecoin</td>
  <td class="ltc td">
    <center><img style="width:20px;" src="images/giphy.gif"></center><span>10</span>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Да, но тут лучше вызывать setTimeout(get, 1000) из коллбека

Comment: @ДавидМанжула Возможно. Вопрос не об этом.

Comment: @Igor к сожалению не работает, даже просто не появляется текст, который должен появляться

Comment: @EmilRotatew создайте пример с разметкой

Comment: @Igor  <tr>
          <td><img style="width:30px;" src="images/Litecoin.png"/></td>
          <td>LTC</td>
          <td>Litecoin</td>
          <td class="ltc td"><center><img style="width:20px;" src="images/giphy.gif"></center></td>
        </tr>

Comment: @EmilRotatew Это что? Создайте пример в вопросе, используя кнопку "Фрагмент кода" в редакторе вопроса.

Comment: @Igor правил вопрос